# Which mathematical operations leave the ontology invariant?

Tags: metaphysics, philosophy-of-mathematics, ontology

So usually one maps a math equation to an ontology in physics. Imagine me [modelling](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105318/formalism-to-deal-with-discontinuous-potentials-in-classical-mechanics-hard-wal/105668#105668) a ball rolling up an inclined plane at an arbitrary angle. Now, the moment I make the inclined angle 90 degrees to the plane it collides with the plane and becomes a turning point. This can be modelled as an elastic collision (0 time duration and infinite force). This trick is known as [renormalization](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/105318/formalism-to-deal-with-discontinuous-potentials-in-classical-mechanics-hard-wal/105668#105668).

Now, I can have an ontology that says all interactions must have finite durations the moment I choose the inclination angle to be 90 degrees this mapping is void. What happened? Well, we mapped force to a number in this ontology and the moment we let force be infinite we remember infinity is a concept not a number and thus we can arguably extended our ontology.

### Question

What all mathematical operations leave the ontology invariant for a physicist?

Comment: Also does this suggest the math to be more fundamental than ontology?

Comment: ???? A math theory assumes the existence of some specific objects and structures and it applies to models that satisfy the axioms of the theory.

Comment: Yes. All my question is saying that physicists extend the ontology (set of axioms) by using a concept (renormalization)

Comment: 90 degrees to *what*? *What* collides with *what* plane? *What* becomes a "turning point"? I cannot make head or tail of this question.

Comment: What is the "mathematical operation" here? Physicists are constantly pushing the boundaries of their models to accommodate new effects, idealized situations (as in this case), etc. There is no telling out of context and ahead of time which model restrictions can be profitably relaxed or removed. This does not suggest that mathematics is  "more fundamental" than ontology, it suggests that it is more flexible than the fragment of it that any particular model uses. Which should not be surprising because it is developed to be this way. The maxim is to maximize options, as Maddy puts it.

Comment: @Conifold I think there are many ways of thinking of renormalization. I am referring to those which get linguistically categorized as renormalization.

Comment: There's a question here, but the expression as stands isn't clear. An onotology is created by presuming and proving the existence of things. We have a mathematical ontology and a physical ontology, and in mathematical physics, we conjoin them. I guess my question is what does it mean to "leave an ontology variant"?

Comment: @JD let's say I conjoin them. Now I take a limit n to infinity (where n is a variable in my theory) and make an entire variable disappear. I have a new theory with lesser variables and I have to conjoin it with a new physics ontology

Comment: Note the renormalization example I have was different from this

Comment: I suggest that under a realist interpretation of physics, if you start with a variable, and end with eliminating a variable, then you have shown that whatever the variable represented doesn't actually exist in some context, and that your physical theory is improved because your math demonstrates that the physical phenomenon your variable represents is more accurate. For instance, consider temperature as a function of KE. At the level of the individual particle, it makes no sense to talk of temperature because it is a statistical measure... thus, our theory can use temperature...

Comment: at the level of human experience, or deny it's existence when looking inside a single particle and we can have two ontologies, one at the macro "level" and one at the subatomic "level". We now have a physical theory that has two distinct ontologies both of which are useful. It's not the operations that determine whether or not ontologies are impacted, but whether the entire mathematical framework matches observation in experimentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149472/discussion-between-j-d-and-more-anonymous).

Comment: I mean temperature is a parameter of a spatial probability distribution and yes with 2 particles it's hard to confirm or deny. I think there's a PSE question about this

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are confusing ontology with simplifying assumptions. Theoretical physics consists of a large number of mathematical models of reality, each of which has limited applicability and most of which make one or more simplifying assumptions about reality. When you switch between one theoretical model and another, you are not committing yourself to a different belief about what actually exists- you are making a different set of simplifying assumptions which better suit the problem you are trying to address. Take an analogy with cartography. You cannot depict all aspects of the Earth's three-dimensional surface on a flat piece of paper, so to draw a map of the world you need to sacrifice some aspect of reality, and you adopt one out of a number of possible projections depending on your purposes. Drawing one or other form of map is not a matter of adopting a new ontology- you are not changing your mind about what reality is but about how to illustrate it.

In a similar way, different mathematical models are used for different purposes in physics, and not all of them are compatible. If you want an exhaustive list of which aspects of theoretical physics are compatible with which other aspects, then you are asking for too much. However, at a high level you can take it that most theoretical models ideally in use in physics are left unchanged by a range of transformations, such as rotations, translations etc, which reflects an underlying symmetry in reality.

Comment: In the use case in the example I give of this "confusing ontology with simplifying assumptions."

Comment: I can reformulate the axioms such that one of the them say interaction duration should be finite

Comment: Sure, they are just different simplifications. In reality, the collision between the ball and the vertical ramp is hugely complicated, involving forces between countless trillions of particles. We simplify it by assuming the ball is perfectly elastic, perfectly spherical, can be treated as a point mass, rebounds instantaneously etc etc. We don't believe the ball really does have those properties.

Comment: I used the word model and can model it's such. QfT is spammed with renormalization. With our classical intuition surely the naive idea of simplifying won't work